# How to call tshark to convert a capture file to txt with CreateProcess

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, wireshark, tshark

I am trying to call tshark from a c++ program compiled with Visual Studio. Some calls work but others do not. I am able to initiate capture to file:

```
STARTUPINFO startupInfo={sizeof(startupInfo)};
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
const char * args = " -i \"Ethernet 9\" -w C:\\Users\\raymond\\Documents\\Debug\\Ethernet_9.cap -b duration:90 -b files:2\"";

CreateProcess("C:\\Program Files\\Wireshark\\tshark.exe", const_cast<char *>(ss.str().c_str()), NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &startupInfo, &processInfo);
```

But i am unable to convert the capture file to text:

```
STARTUPINFO startupInfo={sizeof(startupInfo)};
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
const char * args = " -i - < \"C:\\Users\\raymond\\Documents\\Ethernet_9.cap\" > \"C:\\Users\\raymond\\Documents\\Ethernet_9.txt";

CreateProcess("C:\\Program Files\\Wireshark\\tshark.exe", const_cast<char *>(ss.str().c_str()), NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &startupInfo, &processInfo);
```

All that is printed is "Capturing on 'Standard input'", but contrary to running the command on the command line, nothing is output and the number of processed packets is never printed.

Trying something similar with system() also has strange behavior on the same tshark call.

If I try to close the new widow while the program is still running, this is printed:
(tshark.exe:8628): CaptureChild-WARNING **: sync_pipe_stop: forcing child to exit

Comment: Can you use [boost process](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/process.html) or you need raw windows API without any wrappers on top ? You actually need to pipe "child process" output, open a file stream and write result into file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong flag. `-i -` captures on standard input, where `-i` *captures on an interface*. To read from a file, use `-r <file>` like so:

```cpp
const char * args = " -r <src file> > <dest file>";
```

I highly recommend checking out [tshark's manpage](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html).

#### Full Example

In this example, we create a 3 packet capture, use tshark to create a summary file, and print the results. This should be as cross-platform as `tshark` and `>` are (Windows, Linux, Macos, BSD, etc.).

```cpp
// example.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    system("tshark -w source.pcap -c 3");
    system("tshark -r source.pcap > dest.txt");

    std::ifstream dest;
    dest.open("dest.txt");
    std::cout << dest.rdbuf();
    dest.close();

    return 0;
}
```

After compiling, we can see both tshark feedback and the first couple packets.

```sh
rj$ ./example.o
Capturing on 'Wi-Fi: en0'
3
    1   0.000000 172.31.99.198 → resolver1.opendns.com DNS  80 Standard...     
    2   0.000026 172.31.99.198 → 217.221.186.35.bc.googleusercontent.co...
    3   0.000026 172.31.99.198 → ec2-3-231-46-251.compute-1.amazonaws.c...
```

Comment: -r seems to work on the command line as well as -i. it does not work at all with CreateProcess(). I think the problem is piping the output as Victor_Gubin said.

Comment: @rur2641 Added a full example. There are many ways to get this to work - this is one of the simpler ones.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the redirection operations with `CreateProcess` - the redirections are handled by the command processor `cmd.exe` which is bypassed when you use `CreateProcess`.

You may want to simply use the `system` command from C, which uses the system shell (`cmd.exe` on Windows):

```
system("C:\\Program Files\\Wireshark\\tshark.exe -r \"C:\\Users\\raymond\\Documents\\Ethernet_9.cap\" > \"C:\\Users\\raymond\\Documents\\Ethernet_9.txt\"");
```

As @RossJacobs also mentions, you need to use `-r` instead of `-i` to read from a file.